# Dataset Made of Multiple Datasets

Tags: dataset, cnn

I recall a tweet by Andrej Karpathy sometime a while ago about a ML dataset made up of cifar-10, mnist, ImageNet, and maybe others. I want to use that dataset, but I can't find it. Does anyone know if this still exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the dataset. Its called the "Visual Domain Decathlon"

Heres a link: https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/decathlon/